# Mouse pointers for lefties

Tags: mouse

Is there any possibility to change default mouse pointers to mirrored ones, suitable for lefties? Tried Google and local search - no results.

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install custom cursor themes in your profile using the following guide. You can find other themes that will work but for this example I am using the Obsidian Left theme.

1. Download the theme archive from [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/999703/startdownload?file_id=1460734735&file_name=121197-Obsidian_L.tar.gz&file_type=application/x-gzip&file_size=309862).
2. If it does not already exist create a directory named .icons in your home folder, from the terminal you can run:

> mkdir ~/.icons

4. Unzip the archive into the newly created .icons folder. The result should look like:

> /home/yourusername/.icons/Obsidian_L

4. Run the following command in the terminal in order to set the theme

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "Obsidian_L"

If all goes well you should have left-handed cursors.

If you want to go back to the default run the following in the terminal:

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "elementary"

Comment: Thanx a lot. I've found one more way for it. As I like KDE I installed it right after installation of elementary. And set up left cursors in it. Then I installed elementary-tweaks and found that I could use KDE cursors in elementaryOS settings.